# position:relative leaves an empty space

Tags: css

Code is here: http://lasers.org.ru/vs/example.html

How to remove an empty space under main block (#page)?

Comment: You mean the bottom padding, or to have the whole thing vertically centred?

Comment: Do you mean the space between the text in the #page div and the border? Otherwise I am not sure what space you are talking about.

Comment: @Jeremy Battle I can't figure it out either, though [Guffa seems to have](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229081/positionrelative-leaves-an-empty-space/5229122#5229122).

Comment: Anyone else not seeing this problem?

Comment: Please refer Answer marked at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722095/how-to-remove-whitespace-that-appears-after-relative-positioning-an-element-with][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722095/how-to-remove-whitespace-that-appears-after-relative-positioning-an-element-with

Comment: `margin-top: -10px` is really cool.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Well, don't use relative positioning then. The element still takes up space where it originally was when using relative positioning, and you can't get rid of that. You can for example use absolute positioning instead, or make the elements float beside each other.

I played around with the layout a bit, and I suggest that you change these three rules to:

```
#layout { width: 636px; margin: 0 auto; }
#menu { position: absolute; width: 160px; margin-left: 160px; }
#page { width: 600px; padding: 8px 16px; border: 2px solid #404241; }
```

Comment: "and you can't get rid of that." - you can. Just use negative margin, like in the plang's answer.

Comment: @MichałK: No, that only means that you overlap the empty space with another element, not that you get rid of the empty space. You can only use negative margins to overlap empty space from relative positioning with as much as the size of the element.

Comment: @MichałK: Downvoting this answer and other totally unrelated answers doesn't help, you still can't get rid of the space caused by relative positioning.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't revoke the downvote unless you edit your ansser. But t be honest I don't really understand your comment. In my situation it worked very well (even if not semantically right). If elements are below each other and you reposition one of them up, then you can use negative margin to get rid of the space occupied previously by the `relative` element.

Comment: @MichałK: As you can only cover the space and not get rid of it, you have to have other elements that are as least as large as the empty space to cover it. If you for example have an empty space from an element that is 200px high, and only have an element that is 100px hight to cover the hole, you will still have 100px left of the hole.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: @MichałK replacing my relative positining with negative margin did the trick! Not sure why I only thought of absolute vs. relative instead of using relative but with negative margin, so great! THANKS!

Comment: @AlphaX wow, it's been 5 years. I didn't even remember that I posted anything about css on stackoverflow ;)

Comment: SO for example, I have a checkmark icon I need to display at the top of an iframe, and the icon is positioned so that it's center is at the top of the iframe. I can use a negative margin to "fix" the spacing, but when I don't display the icon, now the negative margin makes the iframe shoot up above other text. That's one of the problems with the "just use a negative margin" approach, is that when show/hide/move elements, things get messy.

Answer (score 235):

Another trick which worked fine for me is to use a negative margin-bottom in the relative element that you have moved. No need to go with absolute positioning.

Something like:

```
position: relative;
top: -200px;
left: 100px;
margin-bottom: -200px;
```

Similar (if not identical) to the solution I see now, from green.

Comment: @plang, Doesn't seem to work. See http://jsfiddle.net/u7sq8rL7/1/ . The green background extends beyond the last element.

Comment: @Pacerier Don't use margin-bottom. It obviously does not work (think about it); you need margin-top.

Comment: This works perfectly. And yes you use `margin-bottom` with a minus number because you want to get rid of the extra space at the bottom.

Comment: I use something like this plus overflow:hidden as Carol McKay mentioned bellow and it did work with the latest browsers as to december 2017

Comment: omg, this so helpful, i just add it to my main container, and it solve.

Comment: @Pacerier Just use a negative `margin-bottom` on the parent of the relative child. You're welcome ;-)

Comment: Essentially `margin-bottom` should be in the same direction and, preferably, of the same value as `top`

Comment: After some time working with negative margins I realized it has no effect on the element it is applied on - doesn't reduce its height as desired.
The actual effect is on the element below, if there is any - it is that element that's pulled into this by a length equivalent to the negative margin.
I therefore conclude by saying that a negative `margin-bottom` isn't the solution I'm looking for - thinking of taking the `absolute` route.
Nice question. Thanks.

Comment: This answer applies in other circumstances, too.  I have a parent div with a nested title div placed with `position-relative top-0 start-0` (no padding in parent div). It was flush top but left 2px white space left and right. `style="margin-left: -2px; margin-right: -2px;"` fixed it right up.  Had same issue with an Accordion div and this solution fixed that as well. [Bootstrap v5]

Answer (score 6):

```css
#page 
{ 
     overflow:hidden; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this rule:

```
#page {
  border: 2px solid #404241;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  width: 600px;
}
```

I changed position to absolute, this allows you to use the `bottom: 0` property.

Answer (score 2):

A negative margin value usually does the trick.

```
container {
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
  marginBottom: -100px;
}
```

Wherever the space appears (top, bottom, left, right)
Just give a negative margin value on the element that was positioned relatively.

Comment: Hey there. Here on Stackoverflow it's discouraged to reply to very old questions (like this one from 2011). If you found someone's answer to be helpfulp please mark their answer as helpfulp. 

This prevents old questions from being "bumped" into relevance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
#page {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

[image: no bottom padding]

Comment: This is the correct answer but I would say you are probably better off WITH the padding as it is easier to read and more standard on the web to have some padding.

Comment: @Jeremy Battle Definitely, the padding looks much better.

Comment: @Kir You can actually just modify your current style to padding: 8px 16px 0px; to avoid having an extra line in your CSS.

Comment: I believe it's the 300px space below the content container that is the problem, not the space inside the container...

Comment: The scenario will create an anonymous box inside the div(#page) and according to the CSS specification there is no other way to control the anonymous box directly and this anonymous box will inherit the property from its parent(in this case #page). So better to change the parent div by changing its property like @alex says. If the above does not meet the criteria then using negative margin is also a solution in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get rid of the whitespaces using the following framework:

[image: HTML-CSS framework]

And here is the markup

```
<div id="the-force-moved-element>I've been moved</div>
<div id="the-hack-part-1">
    <div id="the-hack-part-2>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</div>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is late but it may help others with a similar issue that I had.

I had a `<div>` with `position: relative;` where all the child elements have the `position: absolute;` style. This caused around ***20px*** of white space to appear on my page.

To get around this I added `margin-top: -20px;` to the next sibling element after the `<div>` with `position: relative;`.

If you have a sibling element before, you can use `margin-bottom: -20px;`

```css
section {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Extra Whitespace</h2>
<section>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  <div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="position:relative; top: -20px; left:100px;">ABSOLUTE</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</section>


<h2>No Whitespace margin-top</h2>
<section>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  <div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="position:relative; top: -20px; left:100px;">ABSOLUTE</div>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-top:-20px;">
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</section>


<h2>No Whitespace margin-bottom</h2>
<section>
  <div style="margin-bottom:-20px;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  <div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="position:relative; top: -20px; left:100px;">ABSOLUTE</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: But why there is a gap? Where is it configured?

Comment: The absolute positioned div (` <div style="position:relative;">`) in the HTML causes the unwanted white space between the two non-absolute divs. This is why we need to add a negative margin style to hide it.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution if you don't want to leave spaces below (relative)

Is to use margin-top and position: sticky

```
#page {
     margin-top: -280px;
     position: sticky;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The easiest way is to replace top on `margin-top` for `#page`.

Comment: margin-top with negative value, instead of top + margin-bottom, is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Negative margin didn't work for me as it left a massive white area where it used to be.  I solved this problem in my case by manually entering height.

```
.maincontent {
    height: 675px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be well answered - however all the answers above had bad side effects in my layout. This is what really worked for me:

```css
.moveUp {
    position: relative;
}
.moveUp > * {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: -75px;
}

/** This part is just design - ignore it ... ****/
.box1, .box2, .box3 {
    height: 100px;
    color: white;
}
.box1 {
    background: red;
}
.box2 {
    background: blue;
    height: 50px;
}
.box3 {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">Box 1</div>
<div class="moveUp"><div class="box2">Box 2 - 75px up</div></div>
<div class="box3">Box 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add the marginBottom to the element equal to space that you moved relatively.

```
// you moved top:-120px
// then add marginBottom:-120px
```