# How to remove whitespace that appears after relative positioning an element with CSS

Tags: css, layout, whitespace

The problem occurs is the following:
After relative positioning an element with CSS I get a white-space of where the element was... I don't want the white-space!

```css
    .thetext 
    {
        width:400px;
        background:yellow;
        border: 1px dashed red;
        margin:50px;
        padding:5px;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    .whiteblob
    {
        position:relative;
        top:-140px;
        left:70px;
        width:200px;
        height:50px;
        border: 4px solid green;
        background:white;
        font-size:2.5em;
        color:red;
        
    }
    .footerallowedwhitespaceinblue
    {
        height:10px;
        background-color:blue;
    }
    .footer
    {
        background-color:grey;
        height:200px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="thetext"><script type="text/javascript">for(c=0;c<50;c++){document.write("Lorem ipsum dolor est, ");}</script>
    </div>
    <div class="whiteblob">
        &nbsp;buy this!
    </div>
    <div class="footerallowedwhitespaceinblue">
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        The whitespace above is way to big! The buy this still takes up space whilst it is moved.
    </div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qqXQn/

As you can see in the example, the only whitespace I want is the whitespace caused by the thetext block by the margin of 50px; and the spacing by the footerallowedwhitespaceinblue(made blue so it's visible).
The problem is... the whitespace is too big now because the "buy this" div still takes up space after it's been relatively positioned.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [position:relative leaves an empty space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229081/positionrelative-leaves-an-empty-space)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can simply solve this by applying a negative margin that equals the width or height of the element.

For an element of 100px height that is positioned to the top you will apply margin-bottom:-100px;

For an element of 100px height that is positioned to the bottom you will apply margin-top:-100px;

For an element of 100px width that is positioned to the left you will apply margin-right:-100px;

For an element of 100px width that is positioned to the right you will apply margin-left:-100px;

cut & paste css snippets:

```
.top 
    {
    postion:relative;
    top:-100px;
    height:25px;
    margin-bottom:-25px;
    }
.bottom
    {
    postion:relative;
    top:100px;
    height:25px;
    margin-top:-25px;
    }
.left
    {
    postion:relative;
    left:-100px;
    width:25px;
    margin-right:-25px;
    }
.right
    {
    postion:relative;
    left:100px;
    width:25px;
    margin-left:-25px;
    }
```

And the reworked example code becomes then:

```css
.thetext 
{
    width:400px;
    background:yellow;
    border: 1px dashed red;
    margin:50px;
    padding:5px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.whiteblob
{
    position:relative;
    top:-140px;
    left:70px;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    margin-bottom:-50px;
    border: 4px solid green;
    background:white;
    font-size:2.5em;
    color:red;
    
}
.footerallowedwhitespaceinblue
{
    height:10px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.footer
{
    background-color:grey;
    height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="thetext"><script type="text/javascript">for(c=0;c<50;c++){document.write("Lorem ipsum dolor est, ");}</script>
</div>
<div class="whiteblob">
    &nbsp;buy this!
</div>
<div class="footerallowedwhitespaceinblue">
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qqXQn/1/

Comment: This is so helpful, its exactly what I needed to get rid of the whitespace / padding underneath my div (position: relative)

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example. In this case, the object was moved to the right and then up using a negative top value. Eliminating its trailing margin space required adding an equal negative-margin value.

```
 position:relative;
 width:310px;
 height:260px;
 top:-332px;
 margin-bottom:-332px;
 left:538px;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this problem by giving float:left before position:relative. Use margin-left, margin-top properties instead of top, left also.

Comment: Yea... this doesn't work for stuff you don't want floating though.

Comment: Nice! For some reason, a negative margin didn't work for me, but this did!

Answer (score 3):

If you are brave enough, you may put `overflow:hidden;` and a `bottom negative margin` on relatively positioned element, and it will remove the spacing leftover :) i.e. on responsive site.

But do check it doesn't hide a needed content.

Answer (score 0):

set relative elememt top  to parent font size like this code:

html in jade template:

```
div.dialog(id='login')
        div.dialog-header
            span.title login
            a.dialog-close(href="")  X
            hr
        div.dialog-body
            p hello this is body
            hr
        div.dialog-footer
            p this is footer
```

and css:

```
    .dialog
    {
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: -100%;
        right: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        bottom: 100%;
        border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255,1);
        border-radius: 3px;
        font-size: 14px;

    }   
.dialog-body{
        position: relative;
        background-color: #F99;
        height: 80%;
        top: -14px;
    }
    .dialog-header{
        position: relative;
        height: 10%;
        background-color: #F9F9F9;

    }
    .dialog-footer{
        position: relative;
        height: 10%;
        top: -28px;
        background-color: #F9fdf9;

    }
```

this worked for me!

Answer (score -2):

Set the outer div as "position: relative" the div you want to move as "position: absolute" and set the top and left values.  this will position the item relative to the outer div (not the page).  relative position leaves gaps.  absolute does not.

Comment: Absolute gives issues with dynamic page flow layout. Text wont flow around an absolute positioned item. It will around a relatively positioned item.

Answer (score -2):

set height to 0: `height:0px;`.

Now this div can be placed anywhere.