# Position one element on top of another... but what's the difference between doing it with the margin property vs position property?

Tags: css, position, css-position, margin

I was thinking about the stacking context and I'd have a question about it. Reading I came to understand that, leaving the elements without any css property that could create a possible stacking context (like position for example), you could put one element on top of another one setting the negative margins. So, for example, you have three divs and the 3rd goes on top of the 2ns and 1st, and the 2nd goes on top of the 1st. So far so good.

My question is: leaving the situation of the three divs untouched with the simplest hypothesis (I want the stacking context just this way without altering it so the 3rd goes on top of the 2nd and 1st, and the 2nd goes on top of the 1st) what is the difference in reaching the same solution with negative margins vs using a css property like position? Does this have anything to do with responsiveness or anything else?

I leave you the code so you can better understand what I mean! Try to lock and unlock the different css code blocks that I put between the comments line. The result is the same!

```css
.container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
border: 1px solid black;
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
}

.container div {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
}


/*Effect with POSITION*/
.container :nth-child(3) {
background-color: palegoldenrod;
position: relative;
bottom: 10px;
left: 10px;
}

/*Effect with negative MARGIN*/
/*.container :nth-child(3) {
background-color: palegoldenrod;
margin-top: -10px;
margin-left: 20px;
}*/
```

```html
<div class='container'>

<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: position: relative leaves extra spacing. To read more I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722095/how-to-remove-whitespace-that-appears-after-relative-positioning-an-element-with][1]

Answer (score 0):

The difference shows when uncommenting a "negative margin" rule from container2 and "position relative" rule from container1.

in *container1* : position relative pushes the third box down.
in *container2* : margin negative causes only the box to move and third box stays in place.

```html
<div class="mother">
  <div class='container'>

    <div></div>
    <div><span>hover on me</span></div>
    <div></div>

  </div>

  <div class='container2'>

    <div></div>
    <div><span>hover on me</span></div>
    <div></div>

  </div>

</div>
<style>
  .mother {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 500px;
  }
  
  .container {
    background-color: crimson;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
  }
  
  .container2 {
    background-color: crimson;
    margin-left: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
  }
  
  .container div {
    font-family: helvetica;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: gold;
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
  }
  
  .container2 div {
    font-family: helvetica;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: gold;
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
  }
  /*Effect with POSITION*/
  
  .container :nth-child(2):hover {
    border: 2px solid lightseagreen;
    background-color: gold;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: gold;
  }
  /*Effect with negative MARGIN
.container :nth-child(1) {
background-color: gold;
margin-top: -10px;
margin-left: 20px;
}*/
  /*Effect with POSITION
.container2 :nth-child(3) {
background-color: gold;
position: relative;
bottom: 10px;
left: 10px;
}*/
  /*Effect with negative MARGIN*/
  
  .container2 :nth-child(2):hover {
    border: 2px solid lightseagreen;
    background-color: gold;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Hi! Ok, so basically the element with margin brings with it all the sibling elements before or after it (depending if margin is put top or bottom). Instead the element with position relative "leaves" the place where it sits and you can move it around without the effects that you have with margins.

Does this have anything to do with responsiveness? I mean, how can I relate these behaviors that I see with a real life situation?

ps. Thank you for the link about white spaces created with position, I feel I'll need it!

Comment: no the element with margin acts normal. but when we give position:relative to it, it adds extra spacing. The element with position: relative also kicks the 3rd div down because it has extra margin: bottom now.

Comment: I tinkered with all this a little bit and it's clear. Also, in the first example with position, when you hover there is that third div sliding down a little bit (and also the whole second container!). That is because we didn't take in account the borders. By putting 'box-sizing: border-box' in '.container div' the problem is solved!

Comment: @91Flavio91 thats interesting ! Didn't know border-box could be useful here! Great catch

Comment: Glad to have been useful!

Comment: @91Flavio91 