# Putting two divs on the same row via relative positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I'm trying to create an animation on my site where when a user clicks a link, the site shifts the main content div off the page to the left, and the new content (which corresponds to the clicked link) flies into that open spot from the right. The original content block gets deleted after the animation completes.

I nearly have it down, and what I've done thus far is to use relative positioning and jquery to animate the movement of the divs.

Specifically, if block **A** is the original div, and block **B** is the replacement div, I

1. create **B** and position it off the right side of the screen by setting `left:100%`
2. Use jquery to animate `right:100%` on **A** to send **A** off the left side of the screen
3. Use jquery to fly in **B** from the right by animating `left:0%`

The problem is that after these new styles are set, there is still an empty area where **A** originally was, and **B** is now below that empty space. How would I push **B** up into that space?

Comment: The thing to remember about `relative` positioning is that it’s only the generated box that is shifted. The element still remains where it was in the static document flow. That’s where it “takes up space” as far as other elements are concerned: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229081/positionrelative-leaves-an-empty-space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: I believe your are missing `position:absolute` on **A** and **B**.

Long answer: if you define your container as `position:relative`, all the newly created elements with `position:absolute` will be positioned within the bounding box of the container. At that point we can stick the two elements one next to each other like you said: **A** on `left:0` and **B** on `left:100%`. We can animate both by changing the left value: **A** goes off the screen with `left:-100%` and **B** slides in with `left:0` (which is also the same position of A at the previous step).

You can see it in action here -> http://jsfiddle.net/MVXwT/

Comment: This is in the right direction although the right edge of **A** is still visible after the shift. Additionally will this work if **B** starts from off the screen?

Answer (score 0):

The relative positioning wouln't help then.

Use absolute positioning then.

What you can do is, if you are A to B's place, use jquery to change position of A.

```
$("#divA").css({"position":"absolute"});
```

and then animate it to the position you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

There is a caveat with using absolute, if this content is positioned somewhere inside a container that has a dynamic position, you won't be able to maintain its distance from top of your page. The relative positioning seems a more robust positioning, you should change your display or float values.
To list your possible options to make two divs stay on one row:

1. Absolute Positioning (position: absolute)
2. Floating* (float: left)
3. Inline Block* (display: inline-block)

*The parent container of **A** and **B** should be as wide as **A** and **B** to contain them in one row.

Comment: I want B to overflow off the right side of the page so it remains hidden (using overflow-x: hidden). Will that still work if I go with the floating solution?

Comment: Would I then have to use margins to move things around?

Comment: Yes, It will. You can move them with the left property of the parent. See it for yourself: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/guDbF